# What is the correct way to play Degenerate ogre's pummel?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

There is a monster called [Degenerate Ogre](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/giants/ogre/ogre-degenerate/) which has the pummel ability. however the ability has this odd bit (emphasis mine):

*"If a degenerate ogre succeeds on **both slam attacks** against a single foe it may immediately pummel..."*

however, degenerate ogre doesn't have two slam attacks, but a single slam and a single bite attack. Should the ability work on slam+bite, should I replace the bite with another slam, or just simply add a second slam attack without removing the bite?

Comment: Having done a bit of research on the topic, I can tell you the monster was written before Pathfinder was a thing (Classic Monsters Revised is a 3.5e 2pp or 3pp supplement), but d20pfsrd changed the skill list to work like it should in Pathfinder and decreased the CR by one. The original monster in the book has the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Change Pummel to hit on a slam + bite

I say this, not based on any special insight into what was intended or an obscure rule, but based on the [Ogre](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/giants/ogre/) statblock. Specifically, Ogres are also CR 3 creatures with a +7 to hit for 2d8+7 (16 average) damage and pretty comparable other statistics. Two slam attacks would be two +10 to hit for 1d6+8 (11 average each) damage attacks as opposed to +10 and +8 for 2d6+12 (18 average) plus Pummel.

Add in the significant defensive ability Utterly Psychotic (Ex), and it's clear that Degenerates should not be *that* much better at striking.